# Setting the circle (oval) radius to 10 with others being bigger than the first?

Tags: java, graphics

I want to create 12 concentric circles where the first is radius 10 pixels and the rest have different colors. I am stuck on how to change the radius, and I assume making them different colors is easy. I currently output 12 really small circles. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Circles extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();       

    int xPoint = width / 2;
    int yPoint = height / 2;

    for(int i = 5; i <= 12; i++){
        g.drawOval(xPoint - (i * 5), yPoint - (i * 5), (i * 10), (i * 10));            
    }
}

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Line Loop");

        frame.add(new Circles());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want the first circle to have a radius of 10, why does `i` start at 5? Note that [`drawOval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval-int-int-int-int-) takes parameters `x, y, width, height` which are effectively `x, y, diameter, diameter` for a circle.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. Here's how I fixed it.

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++){
        g.drawOval(xPoint - (i * 50), yPoint - (i * 50), (i * 100), (i * 100));
    }
}
```